# Python csv import of Time Series and reindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

SOLVED

I import a time series from a csv file into a dataframe, it has a column with date/time and data. All values are imported as objects. 
Now I want to reindex the date/time column (to get it "standardized" to 2.5 min intervals all over a time period for further merge, filling NaNs with 'nearest').

I can´t reindex the 'Object' index, failing with:

```
range=pd.date_range(start='2017-10-01',end='2017-10-31',freq='2.5min')
df_b.set_index('datetimecolumn', inplace=True)
df_b=df_b.reindex(range, method='nearest')
```

**ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing**

Also setting the datetimecolumn before to_datetime doesn´t help:

```
range=pd.date_range(start='2017-10-01',end='2017-10-31',freq='2.5min')
df_b['t_index']=pd.to_datetime(df_b['datetimecolumn'])
df_b.set_index('t_index', inplace=True)
df_b=df_b.reindex(range, method='nearest')
```

Format of the 'datetimecolumn' is e.g. "18.09.2017 07:28:33".

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: there is not much more to it...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_b=pd.read_csv('b.csv',delimiter=";")
```

Data Format:

```
[index] datetimecolumn      data1   data2
0       18.09.2017 07:27:03 14,4    23333,222334
1       18.09.2017 07:29:33 13,1    23562,233223
2       18.09.2017 07:32:03 12,5    23234,244644
3       18.09.2017 07:34:33 13,5    23111,373561
4       18.09.2017 07:37:03 13,1    12311,373633
...
```

The output I want (data values from further lines of the dataframe, merged with some other dataframe):

```
[index]             data1   data2         data3
01.10.2017 00:00:00 13.4    13333.222334  13.443
01.10.2017 00:02:30 12,1    25562.233223  13.434
01.10.2017 00:05:00 13.5    35111.373561  13.435
01.10.2017 00:07:30 13.5    35111.373561  13.434
01.10.2017 00:10:00 10.1    12311.373633  13.432
...
```

EDIT 2:
"range corrected to "range1", error remains.

I don´t understand that, because in another df I loaded before it worked. The only difference was the datetime there was in separate columns and I got it with the code:

```
df_boku['t_index']=pd.to_datetime(df_boku[['year','month','day']])+pd.to_timedelta(df_boku['hour MEZ'],unit='h')+pd.to_timedelta(df_boku['min'],unit='m') 
df_boku.set_index('t_index', inplace=True)
df_boku=df_boku.reindex(range1,method='nearest')
```

anything else same, no error (range already modified to range1, not changing original question).

EDIT 3:

Format of the index is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-09-18 07:26:03', '2017-09-18 07:28:33',
               '2017-09-18 07:31:03', '2017-09-18 07:33:33',
               '2017-09-18 07:36:03', '2017-09-18 07:38:33',
               '2017-09-18 07:41:03', '2017-09-18 07:43:33',
               '2017-09-18 07:46:03', '2017-09-18 07:48:33',
               ...
               '2017-11-18 08:31:03', '2017-11-18 08:33:33',
               '2017-11-18 08:36:03', '2017-11-18 08:38:33',
               '2017-11-18 08:41:03', '2017-11-18 08:43:33',
               '2017-11-18 08:46:03', '2017-11-18 08:48:33',
               '2017-11-18 08:51:03', '2017-11-18 08:53:33'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='t_index', length=35172, freq=None)
```

everything monotonic increasing here.

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9c25bfa7e198> in <module>()
     10 
     11 range2=pd.date_range(start='2017-10-01',end='2017-10-31',freq='2.5min')
---> 12 df_b=df_b.reindex(range2, method='nearest')
     13 #df_b.dtypes
     14 #df_b.head()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    125         @wraps(func)
    126         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 127             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    128 
    129         if not PY2:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2933         kwargs.pop('axis', None)
   2934         kwargs.pop('labels', None)
-> 2935         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(**kwargs)
   2936 
   2937     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3021         # perform the reindex on the axes
   3022         return self._reindex_axes(axes, level, limit, tolerance, method,
-> 3023                                   fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
   3024 
   3025     def _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   2868         if index is not None:
   2869             frame = frame._reindex_index(index, method, copy, level,
-> 2870                                          fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   2871 
   2872         return frame

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   2876         new_index, indexer = self.index.reindex(new_index, method=method,
   2877                                                 level=level, limit=limit,
-> 2878                                                 tolerance=tolerance)
   2879         return self._reindex_with_indexers({0: [new_index, indexer]},
   2880                                            copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in reindex(self, target, method, level, limit, tolerance)
   2988                     indexer = self.get_indexer(target, method=method,
   2989                                                limit=limit,
-> 2990                                                tolerance=tolerance)
   2991                 else:
   2992                     if method is not None or limit is not None:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2691             indexer = self._get_fill_indexer(target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2692         elif method == 'nearest':
-> 2693             indexer = self._get_nearest_indexer(target, limit, tolerance)
   2694         else:
   2695             if tolerance is not None:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _get_nearest_indexer(self, target, limit, tolerance)
   2761         tuples).
   2762         """
-> 2763         left_indexer = self.get_indexer(target, 'pad', limit=limit)
   2764         right_indexer = self.get_indexer(target, 'backfill', limit=limit)
   2765 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2689 
   2690         if method == 'pad' or method == 'backfill':
-> 2691             indexer = self._get_fill_indexer(target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2692         elif method == 'nearest':
   2693             indexer = self._get_nearest_indexer(target, limit, tolerance)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _get_fill_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2719         else:
   2720             indexer = self._get_fill_indexer_searchsorted(target, method,
-> 2721                                                           limit)
   2722         if tolerance is not None:
   2723             indexer = self._filter_indexer_tolerance(target._values, indexer,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _get_fill_indexer_searchsorted(self, target, method, limit)
   2740         nonexact = (indexer == -1)
   2741         indexer[nonexact] = self._searchsorted_monotonic(target[nonexact],
-> 2742                                                          side)
   2743         if side == 'left':
   2744             # searchsorted returns "indices into a sorted array such that,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _searchsorted_monotonic(self, label, side)
   3548             return len(self) - pos
   3549 
-> 3550         raise ValueError('index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing')
   3551 
   3552     def _get_loc_only_exact_matches(self, key):

ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
```

Tested:
- definitely no NaT in index
- index sorted

Comment: Could you provide a runnable sample of your dataset and the output you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial "answer" -

I found out what the cause is, but have no final solution yet:

I have the german dates in the csv, that means day and months switched. The to_datetime function converts:

```
30.09.2017 23:56:03 2017-09-30 23:56:03
30.09.2017 23:58:33 2017-09-30 23:58:33
01.10.2017 00:01:03 2017-01-10 00:01:03
01.10.2017 00:03:33 2017-01-10 00:03:33
```

(notice the change from September to October)

EDIT FINAL SOLUTION

```
df_b['t_index']=pd.to_datetime(df_b['datetimecolumn'],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

This did the trick. Switch german day-month-year to month-day-year. That´s why the index "got unsorted" calling to_datetime.

Additionally - the "funny" thing was, if the day was >12 (so it could not be a month) the conversion was right, and the file started in the middle of the month, so the change was not to see with .head()...

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Nice. I think another possible solution might be `pd.to_datetime(df_b['datetimecolumn'], dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the fact that you call your date_range variable `range`...`range` is a reserved word in Python and thus you must definitely avoid giving such a name to a user-defined variable. Actually, changing `range` to `range_b` or something else will make your code run perfectly !

```
import pandas as pd
df_b = pd.DataFrame([["18.09.2017 07:27:03", 14.4, 23333.222334],
                    ["18.09.2017 07:29:33", 13.1,    23562.233223],
                    ["18.09.2017 07:32:03", 12.5,  23234.244644],
                    ["18.09.2017 07:34:33", 13.5,   23111.373561],
                    ["18.09.2017 07:37:03", 13.1 ,12311.373633]],
                            columns = ["datetimecolumn","data1", "data2"])

range_b =pd.date_range(start='2017-10-01',end='2017-10-31',freq='2.5min')
df_b['t_index']=pd.to_datetime(df_b['datetimecolumn'])
df_b.set_index('t_index', inplace=True)
df_b=df_b.reindex(range_b, method='nearest')
df_b
    datetimecolumn  data1   data2
2017-10-01 00:00:00 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:02:30 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:05:00 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:07:30 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:10:00 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:12:30 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:15:00 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:17:30 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:20:00 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
2017-10-01 00:22:30 18.09.2017 07:37:03 13.1    12311.373633
```

Comment: thanks, changed that, a point for sure, but not the primary cause. Error remains.

Comment: Executing this piece of code on my computer did not produce any errors. I am a little surprised that you get errors at your side. Can you check if your index has no `NaT` values as Pandas will automatically coerce wrong values to `NaT` when converting `string` to `datetime`.

Comment: thanks, checked that, no NaT after conversion: df_b['t_index']=pd.to_datetime(df_b['datetimecolumn'])
df_b.set_index('t_index', inplace=True)
df_b.query('t_index == "NaT"') delivered a dataframe with column names and no entries.

Comment: See also my edits plz, format of the index and an other dataframe, that worked with same code, but separate date time columns before the conversion to_datetime. thnx

Comment: I tried also df_b.sort_values(by='t_index') after converting it to_datetime and before setting it index with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, your data `df_b` contains index values that are neither monotonically increasing or decreasing. In other words, `df_b['datetimecolumn']` is not sorted, but `df.reindex(new_index, method='nearest')` requires the index of `df` to be sorted in order for `method='nearest'` to work.

**Solution:**

```
df_b = df_b.set_index().reindex(range, method='nearest')
```

Note that contrary to what the other answer says. it doesn't actually matter that you named `range` after the builtin function. This should not affect the pandas code, but of course, it overwrites the builtin function `range`, which is why naming variables after builtins is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it was part of the solution. Actually (see below) the problem was german notation of the date in the csv.